# Call different methods for different Rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a table with 3 sections with a few items in each of them.
I Need to call a specific method for each different row that the user selects.
How do I do it?

Here's my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // My ARRAYS
    array1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item 1", @"item 2", nil];
    array2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item 1", @"item 2", nil];
    array3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item 1", @"item 2", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (section == 0) {
        return [array1 count];
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return [array2 count];
    } else {

    }

    return [array3 count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Define the Titles for the Sections
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"SECTION 1";
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return @"SECTION 2";
    }

    return @"SECTION 3";
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    SobreCell *cell = (SobreCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SobreCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        // Section 1
        // tituloLabel is a Label in the Cell
        cell.tituloLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        // Section 2
        cell.tituloLabel.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        // Section 3
        cell.tituloLabel.text = [array3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I should probably work on the didSelected row method, but I don't know how to do this

Comment: Please explain why you need a specific method for each row in your tableView. What is it you want your app to do?

Comment: You can do the way you are doing in the cellForRow:
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
 if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        [self someMethod1];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        [self someMethod2];
    }

}

Comment: As a side note, you should have an 2D array (containing all your arrays) so you can return [2DArray count] in numberOfSectionsInTableView and [2DArray objectAtindex:indexPath.section] count] in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: To all of the users answering this question: please don't post identical answers to the ones already posted. That's just not the purpose of SO. Thanks

Comment: @Michael I need to, for example, one item is to open a link on Safari. Another send a email, another send a tweet and so on.

Comment: So the method messaging in the code snippet of Alexandre is what you are looking for? Or do you need a more detailed explanation?

Comment: On Alexandre code i get the section. But how I get witch row was selected? And then call the corresponding method. @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the way you are doing in the cellForRow:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        [self someMethod1];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        [self someMethod2];
    }
   else{
        [self someMethod3]
   }
}
```

Comment: But How do I get which row is selected, inside the section == 0 for example, and then call the corresponding method?

Comment: I get        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                [self someMethod];
                break;
            case 1:
                [self someMethod];
                break;
        }

Comment: Yeah, that's it, you can get the row this way =).

Comment: No problem. The best is that you could get the solution even with my incomplete answer :P.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        // do something else
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: But How do I get which row is selected, inside the section == 0 for example, and then call the corresponding method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexpath.row to identify currently selected row. Here is code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if ( indexPath.row == 0 )
            [self someMethod1];   // Called when first row is selected under section 0
        else if ( indexPath.row == 1 )
            [self someMethod2];   // Called when second row is selected under section 0
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        if ( indexPath.row == 0 )
            [self someMethod3];   // Called when first row is selected under section 1
        else if ( indexPath.row == 1 )
            [self someMethod4];   // Called when second row is selected under section 1
    }
    else 
    {
        if ( indexPath.row == 0 )
            [self someMethod5];   // Called when first row is selected for remaining sections
        else if ( indexPath.row == 1 )
            [self someMethod6];   // Called when second row is selected for remaining sections
    }
}
```